# SQL select max and then display value less than the max

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

For the below code I would like to see if there is a way to choose the highest rev. number in the `PATTERN.VERSION` column and then only display results that are lower than that value.

The date in the column displays like this:

```
Version
--------
2012-03-12 rev. 035    
2012-03-12 rev.035    
2012-03-12 rev.017
```

In this case I would like the query to choose the max of rev.035 and then only display the values that are lower (rev. 017). I attempted this with a MAX aggregate and a sub-query with a less than but could not get the proper result.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"
   ,"PATTERN"."VERSION" 
  ,"PATTERN"."PATTERNDATE"
  ,"SEM_AGENT"."AGENT_VERSION"
  ,"SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_NAME" "Computer Name"
  , "SEM_COMPUTER"."OPERATION_SYSTEM" "Operation System"
  ,dateadd(s,convert(bigint,"SEM_AGENT"."CREATION_TIME")/1000,'01-01-1970 00:00:00') CREATION_DTTM
  , dateadd(s,convert(bigint,"SEM_AGENT"."LAST_UPDATE_TIME")/1000,'01-01-1970 00:00:00') Lastupdatetime
  , DATEADD(s, convert(bigint,LAST_SCAN_TIME)/1000, '01-01-1970 00:00:00')"Last Scan Time"
  , "PATTERN"."PATTERNDATE" "Pattern Date"
  , "SEM_CLIENT"."USER_NAME" "User Name"
  , "V_SEM_COMPUTER"."IP_ADDR1_TEXT" "IP Address"
  , "IDENTITY_MAP"."NAME" "Group Name"
FROM (((("SEM_AGENT" "SEM_AGENT" INNER JOIN "SEM_CLIENT" "SEM_CLIENT" 
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."COMPUTER_ID") 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."DOMAIN_ID")) 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."GROUP_ID"="SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID")) INNER JOIN "SEM_COMPUTER" "SEM_COMPUTER" 
  ON (("SEM_AGENT"."COMPUTER_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID") 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DOMAIN_ID"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DOMAIN_ID")) 
  AND ("SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"="SEM_COMPUTER"."DELETED")) INNER JOIN "PATTERN" "PATTERN" 
  ON "SEM_AGENT"."PATTERN_IDX"="PATTERN"."PATTERN_IDX") INNER JOIN "IDENTITY_MAP" "IDENTITY_MAP" 
  ON "SEM_CLIENT"."GROUP_ID"="IDENTITY_MAP"."ID") INNER JOIN "V_SEM_COMPUTER" "V_SEM_COMPUTER" 
  ON "SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID"="V_SEM_COMPUTER"."COMPUTER_ID" 
  AND "SEM_AGENT"."DELETED"=0


ORDER BY "Computer Name"
```

SAMPLE ROWS

```
IP Address  DELETED VERSION PATTERNDATE AGENT_VERSION   Computer Name   Operation System    CREATION_DTTM   Lastupdatetime  Last Scan Time  Pattern Date    User Name   Group Name  ip_address  device_type user_tag
16X.XX.XX.XX    0   2012-03-13 rev. 002 3/13/2012 12:00:00 AM   12.1.671.4971   MD-EISN-1206    Windows XP Professional     11/10/2011 8:25:46 PM   3/13/2012 7:49:25 PM    3/11/2012 1:00:05 PM    3/13/2012 12:00:00 AM   ECOPYSCAN   My Company\AHRQ\eCOPY-machines  16X.XX.XX.XX    Desktop |fisma-mgmt|fisma-all|
16X.XX.XX.XX    0   2012-03-13 rev. 002 3/13/2012 12:00:00 AM   12.1.671.4971   HHS-46801948    Windows XP Professional     11/10/2011 8:25:46 PM   3/13/2012 7:49:25 PM    3/11/2012 12:00:02 PM   3/13/2012 12:00:00 AM   EcopyIOD    My Company\AHRQ\eCOPY-machines  16X.XX.XX.XX    Desktop |workstations|network scanners|fisma-mgmt|desktops|fisma-all|
16X.XX.XX.XX    0   2012-03-13 rev. 002 3/13/2012 12:00:00 AM   12.1.671.4971   HHS-46801937    Windows XP Professional     11/10/2011 8:25:46 PM   3/13/2012 7:49:25 PM    3/11/2012 12:00:03 PM   3/13/2012 12:00:00 AM   tim.erny    My Company\AHRQ\eCOPY-machines  16X.XX.XX.XX    Desktop |network scanners|fisma-mgmt|desktops|fisma-all|
```

Comment: If __WHERE Pattern.Version < (select max(Version) from Pattern)__ was not working then you have some grouping I could not get from your query. Could you show some rows returned by this query?

Comment: Posted some sample rows, the data didn't format correctly though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, the answer: you can use a `RANK` function as a subquery as beargle suggested above (CTE is not needed here, other than to maybe pretty things up)

```
(SELECT PatternID, RANK() OVER (ORDER BY Version DESC) AS Ranking) AS RankTbl
WHERE Ranking > 1
```

`RANK` will give the same rank to identical versions (which sounds like what you want), but if you want a unique rank for each version entry, then you will want to use `ROW_NUMBER()`

However, this will only work if you run some sort of `SUBSTRING` that will pick out the revision from the date so that it can run the order by properly.  Creating a more normalized database will make this easier, though (see below)

Second, some notes:

- You should not need double quotes around every part of your query. It just makes the code less readable. If you must use a delineation, then use square brackets[]
- If you can, remove revision from the date in version. This will allow you to get closer to a normal database, and will allow you to sort your versions without any string manipulations

Those are just my thoughts on the above...

Answer (score 0):

Use the [RANK](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx) function within a [CTE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx), using `ORDER BY` to sort revision numbers in descending order. Then select from the `CTE` where `RANK` value is greater than 1.

See the sample [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f406a/4).

Comment: Would this work even though the revision number field also contains a date?      2012-03-13 rev. 002

Comment: Nope, you need to isolate the revision-specific data and make sure it's uniformly formatted (not sure if the space between `rev.` and `035` in your question is a typo or actual data). It's best to do this in the database as @Justin Pihony notes, but you can use `CHARINDEX` and `SUBSTRING` to pull out the revision number in the CTE definition as a workaround.